# Know field type usage

Tags: entities, 6, drush

I need to know if a field type is used on a website in a content type. How can I know that with Drush or Drupal BO?

Comment: It is at admin/reports/fields.

Comment: Can you tell me what is BO?

Comment: I guess it is the Views Bulk Operations module, but it would help if the OP would confirm that.

Comment: The OP is asking about Drush or BO (whatever the latter is). I take that looking an administration page is not an option, for the OP.

Comment: What is OP @kiamlaluno looking at the name it should be WP instead :)

Comment: @Shabir _OP_ means _original poster_, the user who asked the question.

Comment: BO = Back Office

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you a list of the fields and types on your site.

```
drush field-info fields
```

Should output something like this

```
 Field name               Field type            Field bundle 
 body                     text_with_summary     page,article          
 field_image              image                 article          
 field_category           entityreference       article          
 field_name               text                  article
```